# place colorbar in subfloat array

Tags: align, subfloats

I have created a subfloat array that is showing different heatmaps that I generated using matlab. This works very well until I want to include a 
colorbar I generated with tikz. [image]

I know that my approach cannot work but I do not know how to do it. Here is how I generated what you can see above:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, table]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shapes.multipart,positioning,decorations.text,fit}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}



\begin{document}%****************************************************

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:1}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_0_rot_0.png}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:2}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_3_rot_0.png}}
  \quad
  \fbox{\subfloat[][]{\label{figur:3}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_6_rot_0.png}}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    at={(-3,-0.5)},
%     hide axis,
%     scale only axis,
    height=0pt,
    width=0pt,
    colormap/jet,
      colorbar,
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=10,
    colorbar style={
        height=0.20\textwidth,                 % Höhe der Colorbar
       xtick={2,4,6,8,10}
    }]
%     \addplot [] {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}
  \\
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:4}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_0_rot_-0_1.png}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:5}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_3_rot_-0_1.png}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:6}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_6_rot_-0_1.png}}
  \\
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:7}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_0_rot_-0_2.png}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:8}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_3_rot_-0_2.png}}
  \quad
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:9}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_6_rot_-0_2.png}}
  \label{fig:sensitivity towards pose}
  \caption{Figure}
  \end{figure}
\end{document} %******
```

I intend to align the colorbar vertically with the first row of images, how to do that?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the minimum amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to help you - and much more likely that they will!

Comment: I took your "thanks" comment and name out of your question because, by convention, we don't do that here:)

Comment: I think they are already aligned. Try adding a `\fbox` around ìmg3 and another one around `tikzpicture` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Andrevv, I'll keep that in mind for the future ;).  And I also created a minimal working example.

@Ignasi: I included the fbox, but how can they be aligned if the vertical spacing from the box is not equal? What I need is vertical centering or something like that. I cannot include the figure as it looks now.

Comment: @martin I understand that the colorbar is the same for all graphics, then did you considered to include it horizontally and centered on top or bottom of your figure? This way subfloats alignment will be vertically and horizontally correct and the alignment problem for the bar disappears. This is just a suggestion.

Comment: @martin I wanted to say: `\subfloat[][]{\label{figur:3}\fbox{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{Depth_n_10m_cy_6_rot_0.png}}}` and `\fbox{\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a solution for your problem but an alternative distribution which can avoid vertical alignment problem.

Instead of a colormap in vertical format, place it horizontally on top of figure.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper, table]{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{float}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,shapes.multipart,positioning,decorations.text,fit}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\usepackage{subfig}
%\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
\multicolumn{3}{c}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    at={(-3,-0.5)},
     hide axis,
     scale only axis,
    height=0pt,
    width=5cm,
    colormap/jet,
      colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=0,
    point meta max=10,
    colorbar style={
%        height=0.20\textwidth,                 % Höhe der Colorbar
       xtick={2,4,6,8,10}
    }]
%     \addplot [] {};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}}\\
                        \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:1}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  &
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:2}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  &
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:3}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}\\
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:4}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  &
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:5}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  &
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:6}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  \\
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:7}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  &
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:8}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  &
  \subfloat[][]{\label{figur:9}\includegraphics[width=3cm]{example-image}}
  \end{tabular}
  \label{fig:sensitivity towards pose}
  \caption{Figure}
  \end{figure}
  \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. That is what I had before. I considered it as a backup solution but would prefer the solution that shows a vertical alignment as shown in my example.

Comment: @martin, thank you for `accepting` the answer, but you don't have to do it if it doesn't solve the problem. You can wait some more time to see if someone else provides a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and Gonzalo Medina proposed a very useful solution in
 **[this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257951/vertical-colorbar-in-tikz-subfigures-png)**.

It's worth to check it. Especially, if one needs a vertical colorbar together with some subfigures, like martin asked here.