# Vertical colorbar (in tikz) + subfigures (png)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, subfloats

I have an issue with the placement of a colorbar. The colorbar is defined separately in a tikz-environment, as suggested in [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120174/creating-a-colormap-in-tikz-pgfplots-no-axis).

My goal is to place one colorbar together with 4 png pictures (in a 2x2 configuration) in one figure environment. The png-pictures are arranged in a 2x2-configuration via the subfigure-command (see code below). The pictures are nicely aligned, but how can I add **a vertical colorbar** to the right side, which is nicely aligned with the 2x2 subfigures (without distortion and maximum readability)? I've made several attempts, but unfortunately without any success. I've also consulted [this topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/240328/place-colorbar-in-subfloat-array), I've just found it while typing my question out, but it seems that it's not solved yet for a vertical colorbar.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[ height=1cm, width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a};
   \end{subfigure}%
~ 
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[ height=1cm, width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-b};
    \end{subfigure}
    \vskip\baselineskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[ height=1cm, width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-c};
   \end{subfigure}%
~ 
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[ height=1cm, width=0.6\textwidth]{example-image-a};
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Random Caption}
\end{figure*}
\end{document}
```

I hope that the question is clear enough. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a tabular with two columns of type `m{<length>}` (requires the [`array`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) package) with centered content. The first column for the 2x2 array of images and the second column for the colorbar. A little example illustrating this approach (adjust the settings according to your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{pgfplots,tikz}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{
  @{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr.1\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}
  }
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.38\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[ height=1.5cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
   \end{subfigure}\hfill
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.38\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[ height=1.5cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-b}
    \end{subfigure}\par\bigskip
    \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.38\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[ height=1.5cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-c}
   \end{subfigure}\hfill
   \begin{subfigure}[t]{0.38\textwidth}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[ height=1.5cm, width=\textwidth]{example-image-a}
   \end{subfigure}
   &
  \includegraphics{colorbar}
\end{tabular}
\caption{Random Caption}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

The colorbar I used was produced by processing the following `colorbar.tex`:

```
\documentclass[border={-4pt 0pt 5pt 0pt}]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale only axis,
    height=0pt,
    width=0pt,
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar horizontal,
    point meta min=18,
    point meta max=48,
    colorbar style={
        width=4cm,
        rotate=90,
        xtick={\empty},
    }
  ]
    \addplot [draw=none] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is indeed the solution that I was looking for. Only I was wondering, out of interest, what this command actually do `{
  @{}>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr.8\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{\dimexpr.1\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}@{}
  }`